# Implementing Google ecommerce tracking code

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, tracking

I am trying to set up e-commerce tracking on my custom e-commerce site. 
On the thank you for ordering page I have added this code at the bottom, it also has the normal ga.js tracking code in the header, as it does on every page of the site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Google Analytics
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31467450-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        transactionId = <?php echo $order_id ?>;
        affiliation = '';
        total = <?php echo $grand_total ?>;
        tax = <?php echo $vat_total ?>;
        shipping = <?php echo $shipping_total ?>;
        country = <?php echo $address ?>;

    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
        transactionId,
        affiliation,
        total, 
        tax,
        shipping,
        city,
        state,
        country
    ]);

    <?php 
    $item_qry = mysql_query("SELECT `products_price`,`products_quantity`,`products_name`,`products_model` FROM `orders_products` WHERE `orders_id`=$order_id");

    while($item_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_qry)) {
    echo"_gaq.push(['_addItem','$order_id','$item_row['products_model']','$item_row['products_name']','','$item_row['products_price']',$item_row['products_quantity'])";
}
?>

    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);
</script>
```

Is this all that is required to track ecommerce?

I added the loop so it runs through every item added, do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it appears that you have all the required parameters. I suggest you test it with a tool like [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/) or [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en).